# k8s: Unable to delete deployment due to lack of RAM

Tags: kubernetes

I got into a vicious circle. I was trying to deploy a few services on AWS Ubuntu machine. It has 1 Gb RAM. By the end of deploying all RAM was used. I decided to delete some of the deployments but I was even unable to check the status of pods and deployments:

```
    $ kubectl delete -f test.yaml
unable to recognize "test.yaml": Get https://172.31.38.138:6443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 172.31.38.138:6443: connect: connection refused


$ kubectl get deployments
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.31.38.138:6443: i/o timeoutUnable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.31.38.138:6443: i/o timeout
```

I do understand that the issue is lack of memory. Hence kube-dns, kube-proxy, etc cannot work correctly. The question is:
How can I delete my test deployments without *kubectl delete...*?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Stop Kubelet service then run docker system prune command to delete all pods. And finally restart kubelet

Comment: Thanks. Stopping the service fixed it.